# Passing file-descriptors between processes asynchronously

Tags: c, sockets, pipe, file-descriptor, client-server

I am implementing a web server where I need to make the parent process do the following:

- `fork()` new worker processes (a pool) at the beginning.
- Looping forever, listening for incoming requests (via socket communication).
- Putting the socket descriptor (returned by `accept()` function) into a queue.

and the worker process will do the following:

- Once created, loops forever watching the queue for any passed socket descriptors.
- If he takes the socket descriptor, he handles the request and serves the client accordingly.

After looking around and searching the internet, I found that I can send a file descriptor between different processes via `UNIX Domain Socket` or `Pipes`. But unfortunately, I can do this synchronously only! (I can send one `fd` at a time, and I cannot put it in a waiting queue)

So, my question is:

- How can I make the parent process puts the socket descriptor into a waiting queue, so that, the request is pending until one of the worker processes finishes a previous request?

Comment: A better (and easier) solution is to have a mutex around the `accept` that each worker process has. i.e. as soon as the accept suceeds, the process unlocks the mutes giving another process a chance.

Comment: @EdHeal The parent process is the one who uses `accept()` function

Comment: @engFouad - Ass noted below your solution will not work. The one that I have outlined will work. (that is why it is a comment)

Comment: I'll grant it's obscure, and it may not even be the best architecture, but I promise you passing file descriptors using `sendmsg` is a real, documented feature that genuinely does work (on at least some platforms, etc. etc.)

Comment: This is the correct answer (@EdHeal).  Just before you call accept(), fork the process, and so all your children also calls accept().  But provide a mutex so only 1 process calls accept at a time.  When you fork, you inherit all the file descriptors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File descriptors are just integers. They are used to index into a per-process table of file information, maintained by the kernel. You can't expect a file descriptor to be "portable" to other processes.

It works (somewhat) if you create the files *before* calling `fork()`, since the file descriptor table is part of the process and thus `clone()`d when the child is created. For file descriptors allocated after the processes have split, such as when using `accept()` to get a new socket, you can't do this.

*UPDATE*: It seems there is a way, using `sendmsg()` with AF_UNIX sockets, see [here](http://www.regatta.cs.msu.su/doc/usr/share/man/info/ru_RU/a_doc_lib/aixprggd/progcomc/skt_comms.htm#SPTSKTCOMPASSFILEDSC) for details as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/909064/28169). I did not know that, sounds a bit "magical" but apparently it's a well-established mechanism so why not go ahead and implement that.

Comment: There is, on Linux at least, a way to pass file descriptors between processes using pipes or UNIX domain sockets. I can't for the life of me remember the details, but I'm assuming the OP already has that part.

Answer (score 0):

1. put the *fd* on an internal queue (lock-free if you want, but probably not necessary)
2. have a thread in the parent process which just reads an *fd* from the internal queue, and sends it via the pipe
3. all child processes inherit the other end of the pipe, and compete to read the next *fd* when they finish their current job

Comment: This will not work - as noted above file descriptors are not universal and just relate to the current process.

Comment: Yes it will - as also noted above, this seems to be part of the BSD spec.  See, for example, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788095/descriptor-passing-with-unix-domain-sockets).

Comment: @Ed Heal ,unwind: wrong, sendmsg can used to pass filedescriptors : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909064/portable-way-to-pass-file-descriptor-between-different-processes