# Pre-fork model in C

Tags: c, linux, unix

Additional to  [dynamic pool of process C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267378/dynamic-pool-of-process-c/16284972?noredirect=1#comment23335789_16284972)

Changed code:

```
   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    ...//settings
    listensock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    result = bind(listensock, (struct sockaddr *) &sAddr, sizeof(sAddr));
    result = listen(listensock, 1);
    ...//skip errors checking

    while(1){
            newsock = accept(listensock, NULL,NULL);
            pid=fork();
            if (pid == 0) {
                send(newsock, buffer, nread, 0);
            }
            close(newsock);
    }
    wait(NULL);
}
```

This creates childs only if someone try to connect. It is not pre-fork model. N processes should be run after server starts and wait for connects. If I try to invoke `fork()` 3 times in loop, it immediately terminate. How to start, wait until someone connect and then send data (like in  my code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent process should not `accept` but just `select` on that socket, and when data becomes available, wake up one of the children. The child will call `accept`.

Pseudocode:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) 
{
   if ((thepid=fork()))
   {
      while (1)
      {
       wait_for_signal();
       int newsock=accept();
       process_socket(newsock);
      }

   }
   else
      pids[i] = thepid;
}
while (1) 
{
   select(...);
   send_wakeup_signal(pids[random()%3]);
}
```

There are several ways to send the wakeup signal (and to wait for one). One method is just `kill(pid, signal_number)` and `pause()`. Eventually however you will need to take the process off the ready pool and reinsert it back when it's done, because there's a possibility to send a wakeup to a process that is busy processing a previous request. This requires communication back from the children to the parent. You can do this with a named pipe or any other IPC mechanism. Look at the source code of the Apache web server to see the canonical industrial-strength example of this technique.

Comment: but how to back to wait_for_signal state in child process after process_socket? It will be just terminated. And how to add process into pool if all children are busy.

Comment: 1. The children should loop (code updated) 2. Children should report back to the parent when they are done through one iteration (not shown in the code).

Comment: Sorry,I meant how to add NEW process into pool(extend it) if all three are running.

Comment: What's the problem? Just fork another one and add it.

Comment: The "wakeup signal" here is senseless.  The children should simply call `accept()` themselves.  Multiple processes can be blocked on `accept()` on the same file descriptor.  The kernel will return from the syscall in exactly one of them.

Comment: Note also that this solution will attempt to "wake up" a process that happens to be blocked on a long-running operation, even if there is an idle process available that the kernel would know about.

Comment: @AndyRoss: that's a possibility but see e.g [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293652/accept-with-sockets-shared-between-multiple-processes-based-on-apache-prefork).

Comment: @n.m.: Linux no longer has that thundering herd problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can move the `fork()` to be before the `accept()` loop, after the `listensock` has been initialized.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    int p = fork();
    if (p == 0) break;
    if (p < 0) { /* handle error... */ }
}
while (1) {
    newsock = accept(...);
    if (newsock < 0) { /* handle error... */ }
    else {
        send(newsock, ...);
        close(newsock);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the cleaner answer.  All of the four processes wait symmetrically on the same file descriptor, and it relies on the kernel to decide which one to wake up.

Comment: @Andy Ross, but if 3 will be all running? how to add more?

Comment: @NatKup: You change 3 to something more. Do you want pre-`fork()` or not? Typically, pre-`fork()` means "not dynamic". Make your question more clear.