# Unix domain socket : sending file descriptor and select()

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, unix, unix-socket

I have seen these question on descriptor passing on SO.

- [Descriptor passing with unix domain sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788095/descriptor-passing-with-unix-domain-sockets)
- [Sending file descriptor over UNIX domain socket, and select()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489433/sending-file-descriptor-over-unix-domain-socket-and-select)

i wrote following two programs to work with Unix domain socket

- [main program](http://pastebin.com/iGAbX7bq)
- [Descriptor receiver](http://pastebin.com/nEs1ix1K)

which are intended to work as

Main program accepts all client connections and send those descriptors to running service program (Descriptor receiver) .Descriptor receiver recvs descriptor and set them to `fd_set and use select` to check whether a descriptor is readable or not if it's ready to  read then read the descriptor into buffer and send string length to client.

`Note : I am testing using telnet on ubuntu 14.10`

Major problem with this program is that `FD_ISSET() return false` even though descriptor is ready to read i.e. Select() is keeps on waiting . 
Some of the time it works , in this case it recvs few message and hang .

I have tried all three flavor of send and recv descriptor functions  but none of them work **perfectly** .

How to resolve this error ?

Comment: Please note that `recv()` not necessarily receives as much data as it was told to, but few. **Always** check the value returned, if the amount of bytes matters.

Comment: It's ok but at least it should recv few bytes <=MAX given .

Comment: Also the code does not always test whether `recvmsg()` return `0`.

Comment: @alk I have all three functions none of them work . You can see first function do this too .

Answer (score 0):

I spend many hours to find bug in the above code . 
It was in  [descriptor receiver](http://pastebin.com/nEs1ix1K)  on line no 153 , Where i forgot to calculate maximum value of recvd descriptor.